# Calculate ampere using volt?

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, charger, amperage, charging

Can we calculate the output ampere of a battery charger by calculating battery voltage over time:
1. Get volt value name it volt1
2. Wait a second
3. Measure volt again name it volt2

So would the ampare be equal to volt2-volt1?

Comment: No. A voltage - voltage doesnt = amperage. Are you talking about the life of the battey, the amp hours?

Comment: Im talking about calculating the charger output ampere. Want to ensure my charger gives 1.0A or not.

Comment: What battery is it? What are you charging? What's the configuration. You need to add more information. Also if you look on your charger it usually lists the current rating

Comment: A mobile battery 3.8V 7.98Wh 2800mA, any way I learned that I cant just calculate the ampere using just volt over time. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help?...

Comment: You possibly can approximate it by using a model of how the battery voltage changes in different charge states (dependent on battery chemistry and age), and work backwards to get the amperage from the deltaV. However, it'd be far better to use direct methods of sensing the current.

Comment: Also note that lithium batteries can be fairly dangerous if not charged properly. Your statement of dimensionally getting amperage from V-V has me worried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate ampere using volt like this:

[image]

where:  $$ I_{CHG} = \frac{V_{CHG}-V_{BAT}}{R},$$

- \$ I_{CHG}\$ is the instantaneous currert from the charger into the battery,
- \$V_{CHG}\$ is the charger output voltage,
- \$V_{BAT}\$ is the battery voltage, and
- R is a [smallish] resistor with a known value.

For example, if \$V_{BAT} = 3.8V\$, \$V_{CHG} = 3.9V\$, and \$R = 0.1\Omega\$, then:

$$ I_{CHG} = \frac{V_{CHG}-V_{BAT}}{R} = \frac{3.9V-3.8V}{0.1\Omega} = 1\text {  ampere}$$

Answer (score 0):

Measuring current is hard - it's not that simple.

Since you are measuring flow, your measuring device needs to be inline.  An ammeter shunt is a good example of doing that - it's a calibrated small resistance, and you measure the millivolts across the shunt and plug that into Ohm's Law.

It's also possible to do it via non-contact methods by measuring the magnetic flux in the wire - this is how clamp ammeters work.